# Retry failed request with pause in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to implement retry logic so that if my request fails due to some technical problem (timeout, connection reset etc.) or error code 4xx|5xx, script tries to re-submit it couple of times with some pause

My code looks like this

```
scenario("my_simulation")
  .repeat(2) {
    tryMax(5, "retryLoopIndex") {
      //pause(session => computePause(session("retryLoopIndex").as[Int]))
      println(LocalDateTime.now() + """Before sleep""")
      pause(5.seconds)
      println(LocalDateTime.now() + """After sleep""")

      exec(http("get_eps_internal")
        .get("/500")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .requestTimeout(GlobalRequestTimeout)
        .check(status.is(200))
      )
    }
  }
```

I have 2 problems here:

1. it seems like pause "happens" only once when scenario gets initialized
2. it pauses for couple milliseconds, not 5 seconds as I would expect

From the logs

```
2022-02-04T08:23:06.404 Before sleep
2022-02-04T08:23:06.408 After sleep
```

Ho can I add pause before each retry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are calling the `println()` is not correct. In fact, `println()` called once and before starting the load test. If you want to call during the test you need to do this:

```
.exec { session =>
        println(LocalDateTime.now() + """Before sleep""")
        session
      }
```

---

Another point is that you call actions without a "dot" and it isn't a right way

```
... {
 pause(5.seconds)
 exec(http("get_eps_internal")
... }
```

You need do this:

```
... {
 pause(5.seconds)
 .exec(http("get_eps_internal")
... }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Does `pause` need to be wrapped in `.exec` call?

Comment: When I did following
`scenario("my_simulation")
      .repeat(2) {
        tryMax(5, "retryLoopIndex") {
            exec { session =>
              pause(5.seconds)
              println(LocalDateTime.now() + """After sleep""")
              session
            }
            .exec(http("get_eps_internal")
              .get("/500")
              .headers(headers_0)
              .requestTimeout(GlobalRequestTimeout)
              .check(status.is(200))
            )
        }
      }`
I see log message each iteration but there still no pause between iterations

Comment: @AndreiStaravoitau no, it doesn't need to be wrapped. just call `pause` in scenario

Comment: finally found out why pause was not working for me. In my simulation set up, I was using throttle and it disables pause. Once again, thanks for the help

Comment: I was glad to help you :)